# Boost (BGL): After calling djikstra's shortest paths I need to walk the tree

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

Kind of a noob with Boost Graph library:

Given I have bundled vertices and edges like such:

```
struct MarkerVertex{
    MarkerID id;
};

struct RelationshipEdge{
    float weight; 
    //there's other things in here too
    //this is the only part that's relevant
};
```

and a graph descriptor like such:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
MarkerVertex, RelationshipEdge>
Graph_t;
```

I call dijkstra's shortest path in the following manner:

```
dijkstra_shortest_paths(m_graph, startDescriptor,
                            weight_map(get(&RelationshipEdge::weight, m_graph))
                                .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(),
                                                                     get(boost::vertex_index, m_graph))));
```

using the `weight` property of the `RelationshipEdge` struct as the path distance

I would like to then traverse the graph from the start to each of the nodes, and do a calculation based on the previous node in the traversal

For instance

- A->B
- A->C
- A->C->D
- A->C->E

then say I'd like to assign "A" to A
- "AB" to B
- "AC" to C
- "ACD" to D
- "ACE" to E

This is just an example, I actually have to do matrix multiplication, so I do not want to start at the end because I actually have to calculate the predecessor values before I can calculate the leaves. Also, some vertices might not connect to the start vertex (possibly many)

What would be the boost syntax to walk from the source node to the rest and do some sort of calculation like that?

Comment: I think this is close: The solution is to add a predecessor map of the distancemap. That's actually quite easy, just after the call to distance_map, call the return value's "predecessor_map" method. The hard part is actually all the typedefing one must do create the right type of the predecessor map.

In this case, predecessorMap is of type:  
`boost::iterator_property_map < vert_t*, IndexMap, vert_t, vert_t& > PredecessorMap;`

where `vert_t` is your typedef `Graph::vertex_descriptor vert_t;`
and IndexMap is type `typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_index_t >::type IndexMap;`

Comment: The ideas for that last comment mainly came from [here](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Boost/BGL/DijkstraComputePath)

Comment: The way to walk the predecessormap is to start at the leaves and recurse until the root, only calculating the leaf once its predecessor has already been calculated and stored

Comment: You might be a boost graph user if you need 4 lines for a single method call lol. Yep I think predecessor map is the way to go as Mike Manh said.